# Set a return value in prolog

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I am trying to write simple case in mod function of two **peano's number** in prolog , put some case it give me wrong answer I don't know what is the problem with my code

**simple case is 
 if C smaller than D return C**

```
mod(C,D,F):- smaller(C,D) -> mod(C,D,C).
```

I don't have output

thank you.

Comment: If `C` is smaller than `D` (`smaller(C, D)` succeeds), then you recursively check if `C` is `C` modulo `D` (you call `mod(C,D,C)`, which will go into an infinite recursion. A big clue here is your result should be `F` but you make no reference to `F` in your predicate clause. I'm sure you saw the singleton variable warning for `F`. What do you really want to happen if `smaller(C, D)` succeeds? (HINT: you want `F` to be something.)

Comment: yes i want to check if this condition correct c smaller than d return c

Comment: Then please read my comment carefully for the hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simply doing this:-

```
mod(C,D,C):- smaller(C,D)
```

It will return C if  `smaller` predicate returns `true`, that is when C is smaller than D.